# How to stop alert from triggering when some data is absent?

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

I'm setting up monitoring on Grafana from Prometheus collecting data from multiple instances.

Each instance produces a metric, which should be constantly rising. If it doesn't grow by at least 1 in 10 minutes, it should fire an alert.

The problem is that the instance sometimes is being reset. For a few minutes it doesn't produce any data, but then the metric is reset to 0 and continues rising. That's normal and it shouldn't fire an alert.

It would be a good enough solution if the alert was completely disabled if in the past 10 minutes there was any absent value.

Comment: What is your question : Detecting the flat lining ? Disable flat lining alerts when application was reset ?

Comment: It's how to stop alert from triggering when some data is absent due to reset.